# Read and write text files using Ajax, jQuery, Java

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp

I have a requirement to read and write bulk of text files at server side.

How can we write using Ajax, Java... Have little bit idea about these technologies but I just need an idea to implement. After that I feel I can proceed. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the text files are going to have to be publicly accessible.  They cannot exist in a private context on the server, as JavaScript is a client side technology.

Once they are public, you can simply do an AJAX request on the file location, and then parse them as required.

If having them in a public location is going to be a problem, you will need to have a page that serves them to authenticated accounts only, so only people that are logged in can view them.  This means they will have to be served via a server side script at some point, which the AJAX request can then fetch as required.

However if you take this approach, you might as well take out the AJAX and just have the server side script do the processing for you and feed out the result.

Comment: its not a problem to make it public for me.becaz only one person can access/write all files. So though Ajax, can we call directly text files and write files? becauase i dont have much idea about Ajax. dont think this is stupid question. Before going to start, i need to check maximum possibilities. Thanks in advance

Comment: ya ..Gaby..  pages should be user friendly. we are planning to use JSP.